# Spinner to display the selecteditem

Tags: android

I'm wondering if there's a `setText()` method in `spinners`? What I want to do is display the selected item in a spinner (it's saved via `sharedpreferences`.) so the next time, the user displays the saved data, it should display in the spinner. How can I do that? I already know how to do it an edittext like this : `age.setText(age);` 
But wondering how to show it in spinners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such method in `Spinner` class.

You need to implement a `SpinnerAdapter` which will be responsible for creating the items of the `Spinner`and attach it via the `setAdapter()` method.

The official Spinners guide may help you: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html